# Color Coded Errors in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, runtime-error, color-coding

Does anyone know the definitions behind each color coded error message given in Visual Studio 2008 while debugging? The line on which the error occurs is highlighted (most often green, and second most often yellow) in different colors. I have a hunch that green is database related... but that's about all I've been able to figure out (far as I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with error messages.  The color indicates the current code execution location after the debugger stopped the program.  It is green when the statement is being executed but some other code is running for which the debugger doesn't have any source code, like a call to a framework method.  It is yellow for the currently executing statement.